# How to Refresh Excel Data Source Via Java

Tags: java, excel

I have an excel file that pulls in data via data connection from bunch of CSV files. The CSV files are generated every now so often by a JAVA program.

Is it possible to refresh the data too via. JAVA program? I see JXCELAPI and JOI are there, but briefly looking at their documentation doesn't indicate my use case is even possible.

In short, I need API that could achieve this effect: clicking on menu Data->Refresh All.

Thanks,
_Madhu

Answer (score 2):

You could try [XLLoop](http://xlloop.sourceforge.net). This lets your spreadsheet talk directly to a java server (or a number of other languages) via function calls.

So you can have your spreadsheet call eg GetMyData("somedata") and it will load the data directly from your server whenever you re-calc (ie. Shift-F9).

BTW, I work on the project so let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial sounds like it might help: [Accessing Excel from Java](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/support/com/doc/excel_example.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [Obba](http://www.obba.info) which is another solution to access a Java library via Excel cell functions (UDFs)...

However, what you describe could also be done by a very small vb/vba macro which checks/polls for modification of these CVS files. I don't know if this is suitable in your situation, but there is an event listener for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed.aspx#Y0